# randomly select images from a an array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to randomly select an image from an array containing the images, but I keep getting invalid props source supplied to image.  I want the page to show a different, random, image each time the user opens that screen in the app. Below is my sample code

```
import image2 from '../../../../assets/images/image2.png';
import image3 from '../../../../assets/images/image3.png';
import image4 from '../../../../assets/images/image4.png';
import image6 from '../../../../assets/images/image6.png';

const images= [
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
  image4,
  image6,
  ];

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeImage();
  }

  changeImage = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    this.setState({
      currentImageIndex: randomNumber
    });
  }

          <Image
            source={{ uri: images[this.state.currentImageIndex] }}
            style={styles.imageStyle}
          />
```

Comment: The react-native `Image` component, if that is what you are using, expects `source`, not `src`.

Comment: Apologies... that was an error on my path while trying to use something different since source was throwing the same error. I have changed it in the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In react-native, when you import an image from a relative path, you have to pass it directly to the source props of the `Image` component.

Here is how it should work :

```
  <Image
    source={images[this.state.currentImageIndex]}
    style={styles.imageStyle}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

This method could work:

Import the hooks:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useFocusEffect, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

Array of image URLs:

```
const welcomeImages = [
  require("../../../assets/img/welcome_1.png"),
  require("../../../assets/img/welcome_2.png"),
  require("../../../assets/img/welcome_3.png"),
];
```

Then on the screen:

```
export default function WelcomeScreen(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [headerImage, setHeaderImage] = useState<number>(0);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * welcomeImages.length);
      setHeaderImage(randomIndex);
    }, []),
  );
```

And in the view:

```
<Image source={welcomeImages[headerImage]} style={styles.headerImage} />
```

Note that I'm using `useFocusEffect` and `useCallback`